# How to prevent Samsung Pay from launching on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge without adding an account and without rooting the phone?

Tags: samsung, gestures, samsung-pay

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge phone. Recently, due to nothing that I've done to it (maybe an OS update?), it now has "bar" at the bottom that acts upon an upward swipe operation that brings up the Samsung Pay app. I never use Samsung Pay, and never want to use it, so I want that to stop being used as the upward swipe gesture.  I've searched on the web and everything leads to having to go into Settings under Samsung Pay, but each time I do, it puts up a login wall whereby I have to sign into a Samsung account. I do *not* want to have to add an account to disable the swipe gesture, as I certainly don't want to allow Samsung to mine my email address.

Is there anyway to just disable it completely, or somehow prevent the upward swipe to launch Samsung Pay, and just do what it used to do before "they" made this Samsung Pay be associated with that upward swipe gesture, and all without rooting the phone?

---

Current half-baked solution: I was able to go into the phones settings, under Apps, and select Samsung Pay, and then click Force Stop. That caused it to disappear.  Is that the way? Restarting the phone did not cause the bar at the bottom to show up again, so this might be the solution, but not certain it will be if a new system update occurs and re-enables the Samsung Pay again.